# Is it possible to have sqlite query that seraches for two keys?

Tags: android, sqlite

All the examples I see for doing a query show only using one key.  Is it possible to use two keys.  I have tried the code below and it does not work. I am trying to find the row where date and time match the date and time in the table

```
    public String getPrimaryID(int date, int time )
{

    Cursor c= db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID}, "date="+date+ "time=" + time, null, null, null, null);
    int id=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    String result=c.getString(id);
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to `AND` your query:

```
Cursor c= db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID}, "date="+date+ " AND time=" + time, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLENAME, null, "date = ? AND time = ?", new String[] { date, time }, null, null, null, null);
```

or :

```
String query ="SELECT * FROM " + TABLENAME + " " + "WHERE  "
                "date = ? " +
                "AND time = ? ";
Cursor c =  db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {date, time});
```

**Explanation :** variables `date` and `time` will replace the `?` characters on the query